# Theorems related to the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading in some course notes on differential equations last year from a URL I can no longer find, and there was a problem that has itched me because I always felt like there was an error in the exercise problem.

Suppose $p(t)>0$ and $p(t)$ is continuous on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Prove that every non-trivial solution of

$$ty^{\prime\prime} + p(t) y = 0$$

has infinitely many roots.

I feel like the solution should follow immediately from the Sturm-Picone comparison theorems, or at least it can be seen from their proofs. But I've gone around in circles long enough to think this statement cannot be true, but I can't prove it one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true as stated. Let $p(t)=\frac{1}{4}t^{-1}$; then the equation $ty''+py=0$ has solution $y(t)=t^{1/2}$.

Comment: I've tried verifying this solution a few times both by hand and by computer algebra systems and that $y(t)$ doesn't seem to be a solution to that differential equation. Am I making a silly mistake?

Comment: I'm very sorry to ask something this simple, but I don't see how you simplified $-\frac{t}{4}(1+t)^{-3/2}$ to $-\frac{1}{4}(1+t)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @JessicaK Whoops. I edited the post; is the example acceptable now?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much